# ViewModel is not cleared for a long time

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have a service that supposed to keep working for some time (2 min) after the main activity destroyed

before I unbound the service in Activity.onStop, but now I moved the code to ViewModel (to make my live easier) and noticed that MainActivity onDestroy is not called even when I switched to other apps.

As soon as the MainActivity is not destroyed MainViewModel keeps running in background for a long period of time.

There is no such issue with other activities, and they get destroyed as I tap on back.

Is there any way to ask OS to kill the Main Activity more often?

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: onStop called, but no onDestroy. So Activity keeps running in background for longer period of time than I expected. While on back button press invokes onDestroy immediately

Comment: I can see this this issue when click switch apps (square) or home (circle)

Answer (score 1):

you can implement `LifecycleObsever` interface to make your ViewModel lifecycle aware. Like this:

```
public class ConfirmDetailsViewModel extends LifecycleObserver {

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    void onPause() {
        // handle on pause senario
    }
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    void onDestroy() {
        // handle on destroy senario
    }
    // and so on ...


}
```